# Navigation bar not fix on top after replacing bootstrap code

Tags: asp.net

i have a simple web form application. After replacing my bootstrap code with https://bootswatch.com/4/lux/bootstrap.min.css  found on https://bootswatch.com/lux/ , my Navigation bar appears a set down from top. please see the attachment below

My navigation code in MasterPage is follows

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary navbar navbar-inverse navbar sticky-top fixed-top">
    ...
    ...
    ..
    </div>
```

Kindly refer to Picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwEll.png) how it should be and picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYAVJ.png) for what i am getting right now. there is a header space showing in picture 2 (i do not need a space there and i need to start the navigation bar from top most).
[image: This is how it should appear, Navigation bar on top]

[image: This how it is appearing now after replacing bootstrap code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change my navbar class to the following fixed my problem

```
class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary navbar navbar-inverse navbar  fixed-top py-1"
```